# Should I use the user's current culture to compare computer names?

Tags: user-interface, localization

I've got a list view and a button. The list view has columns "Server Name", "Operating System" and "Description". The button populates the list view with computer records from Active Directory.

The columns are clickable, and sort the list view as relevant.

When doing the comparisons, should I be using the user's current culture settings, or should I use the invariant culture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use invariant, since neither "Servername", "Operating system" or "Description" changes if you change language.

Only place, where culture concideration are important are when you are dealing with numbers and dates.

Hope it helps

Comment: +1 for first sentence, -1 for the second. Does "ṻ" come before "u" in sorting? Depends - is your culture en-us, de-at or something else? Sorting is not a date nor a number, yet it's exactly the reason for culture settings.